# Redirect all countries except ONE

Tags: jquery, redirect, geo

We have an online store that is only available to our local clients. 
If I put multiple country codes, it does not work.

Is there an alternative to include all country codes except for one?

Been Using this code:

```
  jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  if (location.country_code == 'AP','EU','AD','AE','AF','AG','AI','AL','AM','CW',
'AO','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AW','AZ','BA','BB',
'BD','BE','BF','BG','BH','BI','BJ','BM','BN','BO',
'BR','BS','BT','BV','BW','BY','BZ','CA','CC','CD',
'CF','CG','CH','CI','CK','CL','CM','CN','CO','CR',
'CU','CV','CX','CY','CZ','DE','DJ','DK','DM','DO',
'DZ','EC','EE','EG','EH','ER','ES','ET','FI','FJ',
'FK','FM','FO','FR','SX','GA','GB','GD','GE','GF',
'GH','GI','GL','GM','GN','GP','GQ','GR','GS','GT',
'GU','GW','GY','HK','HM','HN','HR','HT','HU','ID',
'IE','IL','IN','IO','IQ','IR','IS','IT','JM','JO',
'JP','KE','KG','KH','KI','KM','KN','KP','KR','KW',
'KY','KZ','LA','LB','LC','LI','LK','LR','LS','LT',
'LU','LV','LY','MA','MC','MD','MG','MH','MK','ML',
'MM','MN','MO','MP','MQ','MR','MS','MT','MU','MV',
'MW','MX','MY','MZ','NA','NC','NE','NF','NG','NI',
'NL','NO','NP','NR','NU','NZ','OM','PA','PE','PF',
'PG','PK','PL','PM','PN','PR','PS','PT','PW',
'PY','QA','RE','RO','RU','RW','SA','SB','SC','SD',
'SE','SG','SH','SI','SJ','SK','SL','SM','SN','SO',
'SR','ST','SV','SY','SZ','TC','TD','TF','TG','TH',
'TJ','TK','TM','TN','TO','TL','TR','TT','TV','TW',
'TZ','UA','UG','UM','US','UY','UZ','VA','VC','VE',
'VG','VI','VN','VU','WF','WS','YE','YT','RS','ZA',
'ZM','ME','ZW','A1','A2','O1','AX','GG','IM','JE',
    'BL','MF', 'BQ') {
    // Redirect him to the International store.
  window.location.href = 'international site url';
   }
   });
```

This works:

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  if (location.country_code == 'GB') {
    window.location.href = 'international url';
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to check the country code is not equal to the local one

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function (location) {
    if (location.country_code != 'your-local-countrycode-where-redirect-is-not-requered') {
        window.location.href = 'international url';
    }
});
```

---

To check for multiple country codes....

Add all countries to an array and then use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether the country code is present in the array.

```
var countryCodes = ['AP', 'EU', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'CW',
    'AO', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB',
    'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO',
    'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BV', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD',
    'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR',
    'CU', 'CV', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO',
    'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'EH', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ',
    'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'SX', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF',
    'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GS', 'GT',
    'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HM', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID',
    'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO',
    'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW',
    'KY', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT',
    'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML',
    'MM', 'MN', 'MO', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV',
    'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NI',
    'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NU', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PF',
    'PG', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PR', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW',
    'PY', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD',
    'SE', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO',
    'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SY', 'SZ', 'TC', 'TD', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH',
    'TJ', 'TK', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TL', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW',
    'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'UM', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VC', 'VE',
    'VG', 'VI', 'VN', 'VU', 'WF', 'WS', 'YE', 'YT', 'RS', 'ZA',
    'ZM', 'ME', 'ZW', 'A1', 'A2', 'O1', 'AX', 'GG', 'IM', 'JE',
    'BL', 'MF', 'BQ']
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function (location) {
    if ($.inArray(location.country_code, countryCodes) > -1) {
        // Redirect him to the International store.
        window.location.href = 'international site url';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  if (location.country_code == 'GB' || location.country_code == 'EU' || location.country_code == 'GG') {
    window.location.href = 'international url';
  }
  });
```