# How Do I Redirect Using Freegeoip.net Based On Country?

Tags: redirect, geoip, country

I would like to redirect visitors from and to a specific page within my website if those visitors are from any other country besides the United States, using freegeoip.net

I am a relative beginner to coding and I wasn't able execute the code on this page and can't figure out why: [Redirect all countries except ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573675/redirect-all-countries-except-one)

If anybody has a complete code or specific instructions as to what I need to do EXACTLY to execute this code... I would be extremely grateful... I have literally been spending day and night these past four days, on my "vacation", trying to figure this out and I have completely given up on my abilities.

So if anybody can give me the code, please explain it to me as if I were a middle school student... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be a bit late of an answer. Here is the some working code. You can use an AJAX call and set conditions based on the data returned.

`jQuery.ajax( {
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(location) {
                if (location.country_code == 'US') {
                    // do nothing
                }
                else if (location.country_code == 'AU') {
                    window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                }
                else if (location.country_code == 'SE') {
                     window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                }
                else if (location.country_code == 'NL') {
                    window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                }
                else if (location.country_code == 'GB') {
                   // window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: Greatness! Thank you!